# Echo Specific Data from an Associative Array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, associative-array

This is for a recipe project where users use a form and enter their own recipes. I have that whole part working. Now I'm trying to retrieve the recipe's information from the database and display it on a page. Anyway, this is the code I have right now.

```
<?php
include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/recipe.php');
$recipe = new Recipe;

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $basic_data = $recipe->fetch_data($id);

    $sql1 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT recipes.*, categories.* FROM recipes 
      INNER JOIN categories 
      ON (recipes.category_ID = categories.category_ID) 
      WHERE recipes.recipe_id = ?");
    $sql1->bindValue(1, $id);
    $sql1->execute();

    $results1 = $sql1->execute(); 
    echo $results1 = $sql1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($results1);
?>
```

This is what I see on my webpage when this code runs. I've never worked with associative arrays before, so I'm really lost as to how I can echo specific data contained in one. For the purpose of this question, I'm focusing on the "category_name" and I'm trying to echo just the value stored in the "category_name" for this recipe, which happens to be "none". How do I echo just the word "none" to the page?

```
    Arrayarray(1) { 
        [0]=> array(15) { 
            ["recipe_ID"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["recipe_name"]=> string(20) "English Muffin Pizza" 
            ["category_ID"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["servings_ID"]=> string(2) "13" 
            ["prep_hours"]=> string(1) "0" 
            ["prep_minutes"]=> string(2) "20" 
            ["cook_hours"]=> string(1) "0" 
            ["cook_minutes"]=> string(2) "10" 
            ["oven_temp"]=> string(3) "350" 
            ["directions"]=> string(402) "These are the directions." 
            ["extra_comments"]=> string(37) "This is a short extra comment." 
            ["recipe_favorite"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["recipe_photo"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["created"]=> string(19) "2014-09-20 10:22:39" 
            ["category_name"]=> string(4) "none" } 
    }
```

Please let me know if I can give you any more information. It's been a long day and I may be missing something that could help you to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are strictly trying to echo `category_name` in this array you would just write:

```
echo $results1[0]['category_name'];
```

Comment: oh sheesh.. I didn't realize it would be that simple. Thank you!

Comment: It is easy!! :) Cheers

Comment: @bansi True dat...as they say.

Comment: you can try `$results1 = $sql1->fetch_assoc(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and `echo $results1['category_name'];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop to go through $results. That will echo category_name for all recipes.

```
foreach ($results1 as $recipe) {
    echo $recipe['category_name'];
}
```

If you know you want the recipe at key 0 (first recipe), you can simply do:

```
echo $results[0]['category_name'];
```

Comment: that's really good to know. for this project i only need just one recipe's info at a time, but i can definitely see myself using this in the future. thanks for your help!